# Network topology: Internet connected on a leaf node?

Tags: network, airport

Before I go ahead and spend money on new kit, I'd like to run by you my proposed network setup to see if it's feasible:

`Cable Modem <--> Airport Express <--> Airport Extreme
(bridge mode)                          |
                                       +------> Clients
                                       +------> Another Airport Express ----> Clients`

The Expresses extend the wireless network from the Extreme.

The reason for connecting the Cable Modem to the Express is because of it's location in the house.  The Extreme is centrally located, and does a good job today, but I'm moving from ADSL to Cable, and that will be connected on the edge of the house rather than to the Extreme like it currently is.

a) Would this topology work?  Would the Extreme route traffic through the Express to the internet?
b) Are there any problems in this approach that you can envision?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with this as long as both the Extreme and the second Express are run in Bridge mode extending the current network provided from the first Express. Whether that is possible will depend on what kind of signal each receives.